# How to get Application window from android.app.Aplication

Tags: android

I am developing android library which should be able to log all touch events.

I am able to do that by overriding Window callback by:

```
//set Window.Callback for getting touch event 
    final Window window = context.getWindow();
    final Window.Callback localCallback = window.getCallback();
    window.setCallback(new MyWindowCallback(localCallback));
```

I am developing library so I need some way to get application's context to be able to get window by context.getWindow(). I found one solution suggesting:

```
private static Application getApplicationContext() throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
Context context;
final Class<?> activityThreadClass =
        Class.forName("android.app.ActivityThread");
final Method method = activityThreadClass.getMethod("currentApplication");
context = (Application) method.invoke(null, (Object[]) null);
Log.d(tag_, "Context is " + context);
application = (Application)context;
return application;}
```

but this returns android.app.Application and somehow I need to get Activity from this returned instance, because I can call getWindow() only on Activity instance.

So question is, how to get Activity instance from returned Application instance?

Thanks

Comment: That is not directly possible. After all, there may be zero, one, or several windows associated with the app at any point in time. Even if you limit this to an activity's windows, on Android 7.0+, there may be 2+ activities visible at a time, using multi-window.

Comment: Ok, but lets say that i am ok with limiting only to an activity's windows and also assuming that only one activity is visibe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you get application context you can register Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks to get activity lifecycle events.

```
application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks callback)
```

create custom ActivityLifecycleCallbacks (extending) and get activity lifecycle callback with Activity instance.

Comment: This may work to get Activity window, but what if you want to retrieve also window of Dialog or PopupWindow?